# WebPage wording cut off at bottom on Chrome

Tags: css, html

I have a fun challenge. Who ever can solve this first gets my thumbs up/vote. I have done a ton of research I need an HTML expert!

The website: http://www.barona.com/club-barona/email-signup/ has cut off text that I see in Chrome win 10 so far. Looks fine on the iphone. What is causing the cut off? See page source via your browser.

[image]

Comment: Also, are there any other issues that you see? Any new issues are always appreciated! :) Thanks Team!

Comment: What do you need from me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.equalHeight` class to a `height` of `1400px`:

like this `.equalHeight{height: 1400px;}`